# How to get least occurring vowel in string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code that is supposed to print out the least occurring vowel when a word is entered, but it doesn't print out a vowel and the least value. Here is my code:

```
#Program to count the least occurring vowels

# take input from the user
w = input("Enter a word or sentence: ")

# string of vowels
vowel = 'aeiouAEIOU'
min_vowel = w[0]
min = w.count(w[0])

# make it suitable for caseless comparisions
w = w.casefold()
count = 0

# count the vowels
for char in w:
      if vowel in w:
        if w.count(vowel) < min:
            min_vowel = w[0]
            min = w.count(w)
print ("The least occuring vowel is",min_vowel,"with",min,"occurences.")
```

Please can anyone tell me where am going wrong?

Comment: ...so what does it do?

Comment: You've got a handful of errors in here. `min_vowel` is always set to `w[0]` regardless of what character you're looking at. You're looking for `vowel in w` instead of `char in vowel`. You need to go through this with a fine-toothed comb as there are quite a few simple things that need to be fixed.

Comment: ``vowel in w`` is not correct. It should be ``if char in vowel``

Comment: In general, you should read this: [how to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: yeah its meant to be char in vowel , but it's still does not print out a vowel.

Comment: What do you expect `min = w.count(w)` to do?

Comment: That does not answer my question - I know what you want to get; you should include **what you get instead**. Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe my error was that it wasn't printing out a vowel and the least occuring vowel.

Comment: **What. Was. It. Doing. Instead?!**

Comment: Actually that's not correct either, it's printing the first word in the sentence and its count. This is why, rather than guessing, you should *"provide inputs and expected and actual outputs"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to identify multiple vowels with the least occurences, I suggest using a different approach:

```
from collections import Counter

w = input("Enter a word or sentence: ")
vowel = "aeiouy"
# Count occurences of all vowels.
w = Counter(c for c in w.lower() if c in vowel)
# Get vowels with lowest occurences.
min_values = {k: w[k] for k in w if w[k] == min(w.values())}
# Print vowels.
print("The least occuring vowel is:")
for m in min_values:
    print("{vowel} with {occ} occurences.".format(vowel=m, occ=min_values[m]))
```

Example:

```
>>> (...)
>>> Enter a word or sentence: Bananas are YUMMY!
The least occuring vowel is:
e with 1 occurences.
u with 1 occurences.
```

Comment: Hi @user3843256 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.